# What is the basic difference between the ideas of Arya Samaj and Hindutva?

Tags: india, arya-samaj

What is the fundamental difference between Dayanand Saraswati's and Veer Savarkar's ideas of Hindu nationalism?

Comment: This part of this question is off-topic on this site: ***""I am particularly interested in their idea of Islam and Muslims in India."*** Please get rid of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.